# How can I update Python on Mac OS and have RubyGems use the new version?

Tags: python, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, osx-lion

I am having serious issues trying to download the "therubyracer" gem. I think the problem is that I do not have a working `libv8` library to create the gem.

I think I do not have a working `libv8` because my RubyGems keeps trying to use "Python 2.5.6", which is too old to `gem install libv8`. I tried countless ways to update the Python that RubyGems uses, however, I cannot figure it out.

Here is what I have done thus far. I went to http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.3.2/ and downloaded "(Mac OS X 64-bit/32-bit Installer (3.3.2) for Mac OS X 10.6 and later 2.)".

Upon completion of the download, I ran:

```
gem install libv8 --version 3.11.8.17
```

Yet, I still received the same error. I noticed the output still said:

```
"Using Python 2.5.4"
```

Despite downloading a newer Python version, it is not being used. So how do I change the version of Python that the "gem" command uses? I searched and discovered "virtualenv," which appears to be a good Python manager, however I am a bit at a dead end now. Any help or suggestion?

Comment: Python 3 isn't backwards-compatible with Python 2. You should install Python 2.7.5.

Comment: Just because you install Python doesn't mean your session, or rubygems, sees it. Confirm you've added the directory for the new one into your PATH environment variable.

Comment: @theTinMan Sorry tin, I am kind of new to this. When you say `PATH environment variable`, how do I set it? Is this a rails variable, or a terminal/system one?

Comment: You type in "environment path" into the search bar for your browser and press "Return".

Comment: Fair enough. Been grinding around the clock for solutions, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If libv8 uses the python command from the command line, this should apply:

If you do not care what python2 is installed, you can do this in the command line:

```
type python # this gives you the path of the python command
python is /usr/bin/python
type python2.7
python is /usr/bin/python2.7
```

Then you can copy one over the other

```
cp /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

You can safely copy python2.7 there because it is compatible with older versions.

Suggestions?